# Indented Enumeration including equation

Tags: r, quarto

I would like to achieve the following in quarto that works for both, HTML and PDF outputs:

[image]

**Code**:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textit{Title}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\begin{equation}
x^2 = x * x
\end{equation}
\item \textit{Second Title}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame....
\end{enumerate}
```

I tried using the [lineblock](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#line-blocks) functionality, but it is rather cumbersome and do not work for me. Maybe someone has an alternative approach that is more feasible when longer text is included.

**MWE**:

```
---
format:
  html: default
  pdf: default
---

|    1. *First Title*
|        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
|        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
|        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
|        elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
|        et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\begin{equation}
x^2 = x * x
\end{equation}
|    2. *Second Title*
|        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
```

**HTML Output**:

[image]

Comment: why not using [conditional content](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/conditional.html) for handling the case for latex and html separately?

Comment: I would increase code output quite significantly, however, then I would still need a HTML solution. I hoped for something that incorporates the lineblock, e.g. `| {everything in curly brackets is in the same indentation}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [latex extension](https://github.com/tarleb/parse-latex) provided by @tarleb, this works without any problems, e.g.

```
---
format: html
filters:
  - parse-latex
---

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textit{Title}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\begin{equation}
x^2 = x * x
\end{equation}
\item \textit{Second Title}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame....
\end{enumerate}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Nice!!  Didn't expect it to be used this way, but very cool to see that it works.

Answer (score 2):

Markdown syntax for this:

```markdown
1. *Title*\
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
   diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
   aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
   $$x^2 = x * x$$

2. *Second Title*\
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame....
```

On platforms without math support this comes out as

1. *Title*
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
   diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
   aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
   $$x^2 = x * x$$
2. *Second Title*
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame....

but Quarto, pandoc, and GitHub should render the equation ok, too.