# Text that spans several columns in Quarto

Tags: markdown, quarto

How would I go about creating a table in Quarto using markdown where some text spans more than one column. Let's say I wanted to merge the "Left" and "Right" cells below.

| Default | Left | Right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 12 | 12 |
| 123 | 123 | 123 |

Comment: Quarto uses pandoc and [pandoc markdown does not yet support colspans](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1024#issuecomment-621955392).

Comment: @shafee: Oh, that's too bad. And there is no way to include LaTeX tables when outputting as html?

Comment: There is a way actually. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74688908/10858321)