# Quarto will not render LaTeX lists/tables with \begin{} \end{} syntax

Tags: html, render, mathjax, quarto

I've used Quarto and LaTeX together in the past with much success, but recently had to install Quarto anew on a fresh device. Since doing so, certain blocks of LaTeX code have been stubbornly giving me problems. This is surprising to me; I don't remember doing anything special when I last installed Quarto to make LaTeX work, though it's been a little time and the memory may just be escaping me.

If use itemized list or table syntax, such as:

```
$$
\begin{itemize}
  \item Develop and verify the emulation model
  \item Use the model to perform experimentation
  \item Refine the system concept (i.e., map layout)
  \item Report provided upon completion of work
\end{itemize}
$$
```

The rendered HTML doc shows the raw text highlighted in yellow with red text, as though the LaTeX is invalid.

[image]

I've sanity checked with copied/pasted samples off of Overleaf to validate that it IS valid, and get the same result. If I remove the `$$` delimiters, the code is skipped over at render entirely, as though it doesn't exist.

The same occurs if I use `\begin{} \end{}` syntax for tables, but interestingly, not for matrices:

```
\begin{matrix}
5 & 4 & 3\\
x & y & z
\end{matrix}
```

[image]

The matrix code doesn't appear to need the $$ to function.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling tinytex, without success:

[image]

I haven't made any explicit declarations regarding LaTeX in my header, so my assumption is that MathJax is working in the background. I did a pip install of that as well to see if it would help, but there was no change.

So I'm pretty stumped. Is there a package I need to have installed, or a specific line in the header required in order to run basic LaTeX code like this?

Any help from those smarter than myself is much appreciated. :)

Comment: Is your output format `html`?  If so, check out this extension [parse-latex](https://github.com/tarleb/parse-latex) and [this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74642700/latex-table-displayed-in-html/74688908#74688908) may be of help to understand the relationship between latex code and html